# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'

Tags: python, string, integer

```
api_key = '2323'
n_page = '1'

params = {
         'api_key': {api_key},
         'start_page' : {n_page},
}

params['start_page'] = str(int(params['start_page']) + 10)
```

I get this error considering in the last line:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'

Comment: Hint: check the `type` of `params['start_page']` and see if it makes sense to convert it into a number

Comment: Hello, thanks for the hint, but i cant convert it in a number because the api requires string type

Comment: `{n_page}` is different from `n_page`

Comment: Look at what it's telling you:  You're passing an argument to `int()` with an unsupported type.  So, look at what you're passing to `int()`.  It's `params['start_page']`, which is `{n_page}`, which is a `set`.  So you're passing a `set` to `int()`.  Perhaps your dict values shouldn't be sets in the first place?  If so, then just remove the curly braces `{}` from the values.

Comment: I guess you intended `'start_page': n_page` instead of `'start_page': {n_page}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a set inside your dictionary:

```
params['start_page'] -> {"1"}
```

What you want to have is the following:

```
api_key = '2323'
n_page = '1'

params = {
    'api_key': api_key,
    'start_page': n_page,
}

params['start_page'] = str(int(params['start_page']) + 10)
print(params['start_page'])
```